# Problems with CGO and PKCS11 . h in Windows 10

Tags: c, go, cgo, pkcs#11

While writing my Golang code I ended up encountering two errors that I don’t know how to fix. Please, does anyone happen to know??

The First Error happened when I put “import C”, but the GO code I’m creating needs CGO to work so I don’t know why this error is happening or how to fix it.

The Second Error happens when I run the program. I tested and this error has no connection with the first error. I don’t understand why this error is happening or how to fix it, but I already checked the path described and the file described is there.

[image]

This is my main.go

```
package main

// #include "C:\src\github.com\miekg\pkcs11\pkcs11.h"
import "C"

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/miekg/pkcs11"
)

func main() {
    p := pkcs11.New("aetpkss1.dll")
    err := p.Initialize()

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    defer p.Destroy()
    defer p.Finalize()

    slots, err := p.GetSlotList(true)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    session, err := p.OpenSession(slots[0], pkcs11.CKF_SERIAL_SESSION|pkcs11.CKF_RW_SESSION)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer p.CloseSession(session)

    err = p.Login(session, pkcs11.CKU_USER, "1234")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer p.Logout(session)

    p.DigestInit(session, []*pkcs11.Mechanism{pkcs11.NewMechanism(pkcs11.CKM_SHA_1, nil)})
    hash, err := p.Digest(session, []byte("this is a string"))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    for _, d := range hash {
        fmt.Printf("%x", d)
    }

    fmt.Println()
}
```

And this is my settings.json

```
{
    "go.buildTags": "cgo",
    "go.toolsEnvVars": {
        "CGO_ENABLED": "1"
    } /* , "go.toolsGopath": "C:\\msys64\\ucrt64\\bin;${workspaceFolder}\\bin;${env:GOPATH}\\bin" */
}
```

P.S.: I've made a very similar question before but I've put some details, an image and more code to a better understanding.